# GridView/ListView Scroll Into View is not working

Tags: c#, xaml, listview, gridview, uwp

In my app, I am using one `GridView` and one `ListView` in the main page. The aforementioned lists are in a `Dictionary` and I load them into main page as the content of a `ContentPresenter` and this element is wrapped up in a `ScrollViewer`.

XAML for mainpage:

```
<Pivot Grid.Row="1"
           SelectionChanged="Pivot_SelectionChanged"
           SelectedIndex="{Binding PivotIndex, Mode=OneWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
        <PivotItem>
            <PivotItem.Header>
                <TextBlock Text="Home"/>
            </PivotItem.Header>
            <PivotItem.Content>
                <ScrollViewer ViewChanged="Scroll_ViewChanged">
                    <ContentPresenter ContentTemplate="{StaticResource SwitchableHomeView}"/>
                </ScrollViewer>
            </PivotItem.Content>
        </PivotItem>
        <PivotItem>
            <PivotItem.Header>
                <TextBlock Text="Fitness"/>
            </PivotItem.Header>
            <PivotItem.Content>
                <ScrollViewer ViewChanged="Scroll_ViewChanged">
                    <ContentPresenter ContentTemplate="{StaticResource SwitchableFitnessView}"/>
                </ScrollViewer>
            </PivotItem.Content>
        </PivotItem>
    </Pivot>
```

and XAML for Dictionary class:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="SwitchableHomeView"
              x:DataType="data:ItemHelper">
    <UserControl>
        <StackPanel>
            <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                <VisualStateGroup>
                    <VisualState>
                        <VisualState.StateTriggers>
                            <AdaptiveTrigger MinWindowWidth="0"/>
                        </VisualState.StateTriggers>
                        <VisualState.Setters>
                            <Setter Target="HomeListView.Visibility"
                                    Value="Visible"/>
                            <Setter Target="HomeGridView.Visibility"
                                    Value="Collapsed"/>
                        </VisualState.Setters>
                    </VisualState>
                    <VisualState>
                        <VisualState.StateTriggers>
                            <AdaptiveTrigger MinWindowWidth="901"/>
                        </VisualState.StateTriggers>
                        <VisualState.Setters>
                            <Setter Target="HomeListView.Visibility"
                                    Value="Collapsed"/>
                            <Setter Target="HomeGridView.Visibility"
                                    Value="Visible"/>
                        </VisualState.Setters>
                    </VisualState>
                </VisualStateGroup>
            </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
            <ListView Name="HomeListView"
                      Style="{StaticResource ListViewCustomStyle}"
                      ItemsSource="{Binding HomeList, Mode=OneWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                      ItemClick="Article_ItemClick"
                      Loaded="ArticleCollection_Loaded"/>
            <GridView Name="HomeGridView"
                      Style="{StaticResource GridViewCustomStyle}"
                      ItemsSource="{Binding HomeList, Mode=OneWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                      ItemClick="Article_ItemClick"
                      Loaded="ArticleCollection_Loaded"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </UserControl>
</DataTemplate>

    <Style x:Key="GridViewCustomStyle"
       TargetType="GridView">
    <Setter Property="SelectionMode"
            Value="None"/>
    <Setter Property="ItemsPanel"
            Value="{StaticResource GridViewCenteredItemsPanel}"/>
    <Setter Property="IsItemClickEnabled"
            Value="True"/>
    <Setter Property="ShowsScrollingPlaceholders"
            Value="True"/>
    <Setter Property="ItemContainerStyle"
            Value="{StaticResource CustomGridViewItemStyle}"/>
    <Setter Property="ItemTemplate"
            Value="{StaticResource CustomGridItemTemplate}"/>
    <Setter Property="ItemContainerTransitions"
            Value="{StaticResource GridViewItemCustomTransitions}"/>
</Style>

<Style x:Key="ListViewCustomStyle"
       TargetType="ListView">
    <Setter Property="SelectionMode"
            Value="None"/>
    <Setter Property="IsItemClickEnabled"
            Value="True"/>
    <Setter Property="ShowsScrollingPlaceholders"
            Value="True"/>
    <Setter Property="ItemContainerStyle"
            Value="{StaticResource StretchedListView}"/>
    <Setter Property="ItemTemplate"
            Value="{StaticResource CustomListItemTemplate}"/>
    <Setter Property="ItemContainerTransitions"
            Value="{StaticResource GridViewItemCustomTransitions}"/>
</Style>
```

Code-behind for Dictionary class:

```
private async void ArticleCollection_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (navigatedUri != null)
        {
            if (sender is GridView)
            {
                var gv = sender as GridView;

                var item = (gv.ItemsSource as ObservableCollection<ItemHelper>)
                        .Where(compare => compare.ItemImage?.UriSource?.OriginalString == navigatedUri).FirstOrDefault();
                await Dispatcher.RunAsync(Windows.UI.Core.CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, async() => 
                {
                    gv.UpdateLayout();
                    await Task.Delay(500);
                    gv.ScrollIntoView(item);
                    //gv.UpdateLayout();
                });

                var animation = ConnectedAnimationService.GetForCurrentView().GetAnimation(StaticProperties.SquareAnimationKey);
                if (animation != null)
                {
                    if (gv.ContainerFromItem(item) is GridViewItem container)
                    {
                        var root = (FrameworkElement)container.ContentTemplateRoot;
                        var image = (Image)root.FindName("Image");
                        animation.TryStart(image);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        animation.Cancel();
                    }
                }
                if (gv.Visibility == Visibility.Visible)
                {
                    navigatedUri = null;
                }
            }
            else if (sender is ListView)
            {
                var gv = sender as ListView;
                var animation = ConnectedAnimationService.GetForCurrentView().GetAnimation(StaticProperties.SquareAnimationKey);
                if (animation != null)
                {
                    var item = (gv.ItemsSource as ObservableCollection<ItemHelper>)
                        .Where(compare => compare.ItemImage?.UriSource?.OriginalString == navigatedUri).First();
                    await Dispatcher.RunAsync(Windows.UI.Core.CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, async() =>
                    {
                        gv.UpdateLayout();
                        await Task.Delay(500);
                        gv.ScrollIntoView(item);
                        //gv.UpdateLayout();
                    });

                    if (gv.ContainerFromItem(item) is GridViewItem container)
                    {
                        var root = (FrameworkElement)container.ContentTemplateRoot;
                        var image = (Image)root.FindName("image");
                        // Wait for image opened. In future Insider Preview releases, this won't be necessary.
                        image.Opacity = 0;
                        animation.TryStart(image);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        animation.Cancel();
                    }
                }
                if (gv.Visibility == Visibility.Visible)
                {
                    navigatedUri = null;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I switch the `ListView` and `GridView` according to the screen size. So when I navigate back to the `MainPage` after viewing an item, both of the `ListView` and `GridView` get loaded and the `Loaded` event gets fired. I then scroll the `ListView` and `GridView` to that item but it always shows the first item. I have tried various solutions from google but none is working for me.

So I want to ask if I am using the correct approach to make it work. Or is there anything better that can be done to make this work. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the ScrollViewers from your PivotItem ContentTemplates and it may work. GridView has it's own internal ScrollViewer, which is what ScrollIntoView will try to use. However, because you've placed the GridView inside a scrollviewer, the internal scrollviewer isn't used because the GridView has effectively infinite size granted too it by the parent ScrollViewer

Comment: Yes I tweaked my `Templates` a little bit to make it work, but the parent `ScrollViewer` had to be removed.